# Of which sets does the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first $n$ singletons of $\mathbb{N}$ consist?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{E}_n := \{\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{n\}\}$.

The $\sigma$-algebra which is generated by $\mathcal{E}_n$ is defined as follows:

$$\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n) := \bigcap \{\mathcal{A} : \mathcal{E}_n \subset \mathcal{A} \text{ and } \mathcal{A} \text{ is } \sigma\text{-algebra on } \mathbb{N} \} \tag{1}$$

$\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ is well defined since arbitrary intersections of $\sigma$-algebras yield another $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \supset \mathcal{E}_n$, i.e. the intersection is non-empty.

I claim that

$$\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n) = \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}) \cup \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\}), \tag{2}$$

where $\mathcal{P}(B)$ denotes the power set of $B$ and $\mathcal{P}^c(B) := \{A^c : A \in \mathcal{P}(B)$} for a $B \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Proof: "$\supset$": This is clear from the construction of the claimed set: Let $A$ be an element of the claimed set and suppose $A \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$. For every $\mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ I find $a_1,\dots,a_k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $A = \bigcup_{i=1,\dots,k} \{a_i\} \in \mathcal{A}$. 
If $A \in \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\})$ then the claim follows by considering $A^c$.

So far is there anything wrong with my proof? How could I prove "$\subset$"?

Comment: You are claiming that the sigma algebra generated by $n$ singletons has two elements?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. You are absolutely right, my post makes no sense. I wanted to say that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ contains all sets of the power set of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and their complements.

Comment: You don't need the $\mathcal (P)^c$ since as $A$ ranges over the subsets of $B$ so does $A^c.$ What I mean is your definition of $\sigma(\mathcal (E)_n)$ could instead be simply the power set of $\{1,...,n\}.$

Comment: @coffeemath: I am not sure, which definition of $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ you are referring to (edited the post, tagging both statements). My goal is to **list** all sets that are element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}_n$. Obviously, if $\mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ I don't need to prove the same for the complement, since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under the formation of complements.

Comment: I was just pointing out that your claim could be simplified to just saying that $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ was the power set of $\{1,...,n\}.$ Making the claim simpler seems better proof format, in my opinion.

Comment: @coffeemath: But then I would be missing out on a lot (all the complements). Note that $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$. I think if $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ was a $\sigma$-algebra on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ the simplification would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove "$\subset$" goes by proving that

$$\Sigma := \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}) \cup \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\})$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{E}_n$. By the definition of $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n)$ the inclusion $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n) \subset \Sigma$ follows.

> For this proof, I found it useful to show the following identity:
>
> $$
>   \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\}) 
>  = \left\{  A : A \supset \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\dots,n\} \right\}
>  $$
>
> **Proof:** "$\subset$": Let $A \in \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\})$. By Definition $A^c \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$. This implies
>
> $$
> A = (A^c)^c \supset \{1,\dots,n\}^c = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\dots,n\}.
> $$
>
> The other inclusion is proven analogously.

To prove that $\Sigma$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra it is necessary to check

- **$\emptyset, \mathbb{N} \in \Sigma$** : This is clear from the construction of $\Sigma$
- **$A \in \Sigma \implies A^c \in \sigma$** : Once again this follows from the definition of $\Sigma$
- **Closedness with respect to countable disjoint unions**:

Let $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of sets with $A_k \in \Sigma$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A_j \cap A_k = \emptyset$ for $j \neq k$.  Suppose that

$$
A_k \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}) \text{, for all } k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Since $\mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\{1,\dots,n\}$

$$
\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k \in \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}).
$$

Now suppose there is a $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_j \in \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\})$. It can be shown that this implies

$$
\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k \in \mathcal{P}^c(\{1,\dots,n\}).
$$

Since 
$$
\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k 
\supset A_j 
\supset \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1,\dots,n\},
$$ 
this claim follows and all conditions for $\Sigma$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra are fulfilled.

Since $\mathcal{E}_n \subset \mathcal{P}(\{1,\dots,n\}) \subset \Sigma$, this implies $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_n) \subset \Sigma$.